# Are brassica oleracea cultivars the same species?

Tags: botany

I used to think *Brassica oleracea* cultivars (*e.g.*, kale, cabbage) were different species originating from the same species *Brassica oleracea*.
But it seems I were wrong, right?

If so can we breed two different cultivars with each other, *e.g.*, cabbage + cauliflower?

Answer (score 4):

Cultivars are, per definition, the same species of plants. Animal breeds are the same species too, think of the bewildering phenotypical variety of dogs for example; they are still the same species, *i.e.*, *Canis lupus*.

To your question - Yes, [**cabbage, broccoli, cauliflower, and Brussels sprouts are the same species**](http://progressnews.blogspot.nl/2011/04/cabbage-broccoli-and-brussels-sprouts.html).

Hybrids of these plants are called cultivars; broccoli and cauliflower yields [**broccoflower**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broccoflower) for example. However, I wasn't able to find evidence of a hybrid between cabbage and cauliflower - a cabbaflower?

Answer (score 1):

These are the same species. There are people working on new cultivars. This species can also cross with some of the other brassicas - search for 'The Triangle of U' for further information on interspecific hybrids in this group.